# how is it possible to intern macros in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to do something like this for debugging purposes:

```
(intern 'clojure.core 'doc clojure.repl/doc)
```

but it is not letting me because the compiler says - cant take value of a macro.

is there another way?

Comment: Sorry but not following, you need something like partial or curry?

Comment: so I can do this: 
(intern 'clojure.core 'pprint  clojure.pprint/pprint)

Comment: but if the function is a macro, I can't intern it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A macro is a function stored in a Var with `:macro true` in its metadata map. So, you can

1. obtain the macro function itself by `deref`ing the Var:

   ```
   @#'doc
   ```
2. use `intern` to install a function as a macro by attaching appropriate metadata to the name symbol (see `(doc intern)` which promises to transfer any metadata provided in this way to the Var):

   ```
   (intern 'clojure.core
           (with-meta 'doc {:macro true})
           @#'clojure.repl/doc)
   ```

Using reader metadata is possible too, just remember to put it "inside the quote":

```
;; attaches metadata to the symbol, which is what we want:
' ^:macro doc

;; attaches metadata to the list structure (quote doc):
^:macro 'doc
```

`^:macro` is shorthand for `^{:macro true}`.